# Compile and export in java via Terminal

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a Java program in Eclipse on Mac currently, and I normally have to use multiple clicks just to export my code into a .jar file to test on my server. I would like to automate the process via terminal.

Basically, I compile my code usually by selecting the project

1. Export as Runnable JAR file
2. Select library handling: extract required libarires into generated JAR
3. Select export destination and hit done.

How can I do this via terminal? I assume this would first require me to compile the Java file, then to convert it to jar is a whole another step.

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can create shell script that does it. This technique is obsolete since ~1998. So, use one of popular build tools. If you are starting now take a look on [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/). Although there are a lot of other tools: good old ant, maven, buildr, ivy etc.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create default entry point manifest file as in : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html
2. Open Terminal and create an executable jar file like this:

Sample Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# set CLASSPATH if needed
cd workspace/src
javac -d . *.java
jar tf exported.jar .
```

Comment: Doesn't it need a Manifest?

Comment: What if i have .jar files that i rely on outside of the project folder?

Comment: @Djon: Thanks, added that step as well.

Comment: @user1436508 You can set the `Class-Path` attribute in the Manifest.

Comment: @user1436508: That's why I added that comment: `# set CLASSPATH if needed`

Comment: It throws me 10 million errors as I have .jar files outside my main folder that I need to compile in too. hence i have a ton of cannot find symbol errors.

Comment: Could i have an example? I am not very familar with Linux/Unix or shell scripting. doesnt # mean comment out? how do i set CLASSPATH?

Comment: If you're trying to automate it then you will need to do this 1 time setup of collecting all required JAR files and put them into `Class-Path`

Comment: @user1436508: Pls check this link as an example of setting Class-Path in Manifest: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html

Comment: I cant even compile my class...it requires .Jar files

Comment: Yes those JAR files are one that you need to specify in Class-Path as per the link above.

Answer (score 1):

You can script all these activities using a build script. Several libraries exist for this, but Apache Ant is a good place to start. Ant build scripts can be run from command line or within eclipse, and will do all compilation, packaging and (some) deployment for you with a single command.

http://ant.apache.org/